# Not resolve Theme and style from Android Module by `api` method

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I created an Android module by `Kotlin` called `AModule` and I use custom `Style\Theme` inside it.
`AModule` need to more dependencies and I imported dependency by **`api`** configuration **`gradle`** method. one of library is `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07`

When I import `AModule` to my Application by `implementation` Android throw exception that can not Resolve Styles
but when I use **`compile`** method Instead of ‍‍‍‍‍‍**`api`** problem did solve. but **`compile`** method has deprecated.

Now What method to use that resolve `Style\Theme` like **`compile`**?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

delete these from `build.gradle` if you have them:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Then ->
 1. Sync
 2. Undo delete
 3. Sync again